# Logging Simultaneous Open Connection Establishment With Iptables

Tags: iptables, logging, tcp

Simultaneous Open Connection Establishment: TCP is also set up to handle the situation where both devices perform an active OPEN instead of one doing a passive OPEN. This may occur if two clients are trying to reach each other instead of a client and a server. It is uncommon, however, and only happens under certain circumstances.Simultaneous connection establishment can also only happen if a well-known port is used as the source port for one of the devices.

Now, if i want to log tcp connections and also consider Simultaneous Open Connection Establishment, is it possible that with iptables?

in fact because iptables is state-less, can iptables log Simultaneous Open Connection Establishment?

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe that this might actually happen? It isn't just uncommon; it's extraordinarily rare.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i know that, but i want to know can iptables handle it because it is state-less or i should handle that situation with snort ids?

Comment: And also split-handshake is another tcp connection mechanisms! Can iptables handle that situation too?!